# sudo chmod is invalid when using mounted-partition(windows)?

Tags: linux, shell, filesystems, ubuntu-12.04

```
# /etc/fstab
UUID=D254B*****B5B*** /home/username/c ntfs defaults,fmask=113,dmask=002,    uid=username,gid=username 0 2

# uname -a
Linux 00544 3.2.0-37-generic-pae #58-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 24 15:51:02 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

if 'test.tmp' is a file in windows c partition and I mount C partition in Linux;
The commond 'sudo chmod u+x test.tmp' is invalid ,why? and How ?
many thanks! ^_^

Comment: If you mount an ntfs-partition, you cannot use chmod, it is determined by the partition's mount options. No way around that.

Comment: @ruakh I mean the chmod commond don't work.it cannot +x to a file.

Answer (score 4):

It's invalid because the underlying file-system has no notion of these POSIX things.  The OS "pretends" (using the mount options) that they exist. But they don't.